# Java logging - Default logging level

Tags: java, logging

What exactly is the purpose of default logging level in my log property file? E.g.:

```
.level = INFO
```

If I log something, I have to provide a log level anyways:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Log some error")
```

So whats the point of defining a default log level if it overridden anyways?

Comment: That's not log4j, that's java.util.logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first line defines *what comes out*. The call to 'log' marks that message as SEVERE. The .level line says, 'output anything at INFO or more severe'. So a call to log at level DETAIL or DEBUG or whatever would be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

It is not overriden.

the .level=INFO doesn't define a filter, it defines a threshold.

The log INFO is a "level". The default levels are

TRACE,
DEBUG,
INFO,
WARN,
ERROR and
FATAL

If your current level is INFO then any logs with level INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL are printed

If your current level is ERROR then any logs with level ERROR and FATAL are printed.